# Conditionally choose method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this:

```
def some_method()
   if auto_pagination
    customers_list.auto_paging_each do |customer|
     customer_hash = importer.extract(customer)
     arr << customer_hash
    end
  else
    customers_list.each do |customer|
    customer_hash = importer.extract(customer)
    arr << customer_hash
    end
  end
end
```

I would like to refactor it in a shorter version. I though about send method but with the block I turns out a bit tricky. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I though about send method but with the block I turns out a bit tricky

I'm not sure what you mean by "tricky", but:

```
def some_method()
  method_name = auto_pagination ? :auto_paging_each : :each

  customers_list.send(method_name) do |customer|
    customer_hash = importer.extract(customer)
    arr << customer_hash
  end
end
```

Comment: yeah, In the end it was as simply as this. Thanks anyway

Comment: @TomLord : IMO, `public_send` instead of `send` would be more equivalent to the original code of the OP.